# Java hashmap returns null

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I'm receiving a null value from my hashmap. This is the hashmap creation:

```
private HashMap<String,Bitmap> thumbs = new HashMap<String,Bitmap>();

/* adding a single value to the hashmap */
```

Then I proceed to retreiving the value from the hashmap, like so:

```
    public Bitmap getImageByFileName(String fileName) {

    Bitmap fish = null;
    Iterator it = thumbs.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        fish = (Bitmap)thumbs.get(fileName);        
        it.remove(); 
    }   
    Log.i("shnitzel", " bitmap is " + fish);
    fish = (Bitmap)thumbs.get(fileName);
    Log.i("shnitzel", " final bitmap is " + fish);
    return fish;
}
```

The log file:

```
08-05 22:18:28.170: I/shnitzel(477):  bitmap is android.graphics.Bitmap@40650138
08-05 22:18:28.170: I/shnitzel(477):  final bitmap is null
```

As you can see, I use the exact same command inside and outside the 'while' loop, but for some reason it works inside it, but not outside. Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you not removing it in the while loop?

Comment: :(
Embarrassing indeed. I actually only added this while loop to see why I was receiving a null value to begin with. I honestly have no idea why it didn't work before, but does now. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Glad to hear the problem's solved! Please select an answer to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it.remove()` is removing the entry from the HashMap.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29):

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop:

```
it.remove();
```

You're removing the element after having read it.